# How to enumerate the elements of a list by `Fin`s in linear time?

Tags: time-complexity, agda, dependent-type, idris

We can enumerate the elements of a list like this:

```
-- enumerate-ℕ = zip [0..]
enumerate-ℕ : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> List A -> List (ℕ × A)
enumerate-ℕ = go 0 where
  go : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> ℕ -> List A -> List (ℕ × A)
  go n  []      = []
  go n (x ∷ xs) = (n , x) ∷ go (ℕ.suc n) xs
```

E.g. `enumerate-ℕ (1 ∷ 3 ∷ 2 ∷ 5 ∷ [])` is equal to `(0 , 1) ∷ (1 , 3) ∷ (2 , 2) ∷ (3 , 5) ∷ []`. Assuming there is sharing in Agda, the function is linear.

However if we try to enumerate the elements of a list by `Fin`s rather than `ℕ`s, the function becomes quadratic:

```
enumerate-Fin : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (xs : List A) -> List (Fin (length xs) × A)
enumerate-Fin  []      = []
enumerate-Fin (x ∷ xs) = (zero , x) ∷ map (pmap suc id) (enumerate-Fin xs)
```

Is it possible to enumerate by `Fin`s in linear time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this as a first attempt:

```
go : ∀ {m α} {A : Set α} -> Fin m -> (xs : List A) -> List (Fin (m + length xs) × A)
go i  []      = []
go i (x ∷ xs) = (inject+ _ i , x) ∷ {!go (suc i) xs!}
```

`i` grows at each recursive call as it should, but there is a mismatch:

the type of the goal is `List (Fin (.m + suc (length xs)) × .A)`

the type of the expression insise the hole is `List (Fin (suc (.m + length xs)) × .A)`

It's easy to prove that two types are equal, but it's also dirty. This is a common problem: one argument grows and the other lowers, so we need definitionally commutative `_+_` to handle both the cases, but there is no way to define it. The solution is to use CPS:

```
go : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (k : ℕ -> ℕ) -> (xs : List A) -> List (Fin (k (length xs)) × A)
go k  []      = []
go k (x ∷ xs) = ({!!} , x) ∷ go (k ∘ suc) xs
```

`(k ∘ suc) (length xs)` is the same thing as `k (length (x ∷ xs))`, hence the mismatch is fixed, but what is `i` now? The type of the hole is `Fin (k (suc (length xs)))` and it's uninhabited in the current context, so let's introduce some inhabitant:

```
go : ∀ {α} {A : Set α}
   -> (k : ℕ -> ℕ)
   -> (∀ {n} -> Fin (k (suc n)))
   -> (xs : List A)
   -> List (Fin (k (length xs)) × A)
go k i  []      = []
go k i (x ∷ xs) = (i , x) ∷ go (k ∘ suc) {!!} xs
```

The type of the new hole is `{n : ℕ} → Fin (k (suc (suc n)))`. We can fill it with `i`, but `i` must grow at each recursive call. However `suc` and `k` doesn't commute, so `suc i` is `Fin (suc (k (suc (_n_65 k i x xs))))`. So we add another argument that `suc`s under `k`, and the final definition is

```
enumerate-Fin : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (xs : List A) -> List (Fin (length xs) × A)
enumerate-Fin = go id suc zero where
  go : ∀ {α} {A : Set α}
     -> (k : ℕ -> ℕ)
     -> (∀ {n} -> Fin (k n) -> Fin (k (suc n)))
     -> (∀ {n} -> Fin (k (suc n)))
     -> (xs : List A)
     -> List (Fin (k (length xs)) × A)
  go k s i  []      = []
  go k s i (x ∷ xs) = (i , x) ∷ go (k ∘ suc) s (s i) xs
```

which works, because `s : {n : ℕ} → Fin (k n) → Fin (k (suc n))` can be treated as `{n : ℕ} → Fin (k (suc n)) → Fin (k (suc (suc n)))`.

A test: `C-c C-n` `enumerate-Fin (1 ∷ 3 ∷ 2 ∷ 5 ∷ [])` gives

```
(zero , 1) ∷
(suc zero , 3) ∷
(suc (suc zero) , 2) ∷ (suc (suc (suc zero)) , 5) ∷ []
```

---

Now note that in `enumerate-Fin` `k` always follows `Fin` in the types. Hence we can abstract `Fin ∘ k` and get a generic version of the function that works with both `ℕ` and `Fin`:

```
genumerate : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α}
           -> (B : ℕ -> Set β)
           -> (∀ {n} -> B n -> B (suc n))
           -> (∀ {n} -> B (suc n))
           -> (xs : List A)
           -> List (B (length xs) × A)
genumerate B s i  []      = []
genumerate B s i (x ∷ xs) = (i , x) ∷ genumerate (B ∘ suc) s (s i) xs

enumerate-ℕ : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> List A -> List (ℕ × A)
enumerate-ℕ = genumerate _ suc 0

enumerate-Fin : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> (xs : List A) -> List (Fin (length xs) × A)
enumerate-Fin = genumerate Fin suc zero
```