# How to implement Floyd's Hare and Tortoise algorithm in Agda?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, agda, theorem-proving, floyd-cycle-finding

I want to translate the following Haskell code into Agda:

```hs
import Control.Arrow (first)
import Control.Monad (join)

safeTail :: [a] -> [a]
safeTail []     = []
safeTail (_:xs) = xs

floyd :: [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
floyd xs     []     = ([], xs)
floyd (x:xs) (_:ys) = first (x:) $ floyd xs (safeTail ys)

split :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
split = join floyd
```

This allows us to efficiently split a list into two:

```hs
split [1,2,3,4,5]   = ([1,2,3], [4,5])
split [1,2,3,4,5,6] = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

So, I tried to convert this code to Agda:

```
floyd : {A : Set} → List A → List A → List A × List A
floyd xs        []        = ([] , xs)
floyd (x :: xs) (_ :: ys) = first (x ::_) (floyd xs (safeTail ys))
```

The only problem is that Agda complains that I'm missing the case for `floyd [] (y :: ys)`. However, this case should never arise. How can I prove to Agda that this case should never arise?

---

Here's a visual example of how this algorithm works:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|   Tortoise  |     Hare    |
+-------------+-------------+
| ^ 1 2 3 4 5 | ^ 1 2 3 4 5 |
| 1 ^ 2 3 4 5 | 1 2 ^ 3 4 5 |
| 1 2 ^ 3 4 5 | 1 2 3 4 ^ 5 |
| 1 2 3 ^ 4 5 | 1 2 3 4 5 ^ |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Here's another example:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|    Tortoise   |      Hare     |
+---------------+---------------+
| ^ 1 2 3 4 5 6 | ^ 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
| 1 ^ 2 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 ^ 3 4 5 6 |
| 1 2 ^ 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 ^ 5 6 |
| 1 2 3 ^ 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 ^ |
+---------------+---------------+
```

When the hare (the second argument to `floyd`) reaches the end of the list, the tortoise (the first argument to `floyd`) reaches the middle of the list. Thus, by using two pointers (the second one moving twice as fast as the first) we can efficiently split a list into two.

Comment: [Why](http://ideone.com/aKcgNZ) the accumulator?

Comment: @user3237465 For efficient tail recursion. Either way, it doesn't make any difference to the actual problem.

Comment: This `floyd acc [] (y ∷ ys)` case can arise, just by calling that function directly. You could give it a dummy implementation.

Comment: @TwanvanLaarhoven Indeed, it could arise if we call the `floyd` function directly. However, we're not supposed to. The Haskell type for the `floyd` function is too permissive. I was hoping we could give `floyd` a stricter type in Agda. Perhaps a dependent type?

Comment: @Aadit M Shah, it's not efficient — it's unnecessary strict, which means that you can't garbage collect elements of a list as soon as possible, which results in very bad performance. Nobody defines functions like `map`, `_++_` and others using tail recursion, especially in a dependently-typed setting.

Comment: You could give it the type `floyd : {A : Set} → List A → (xs : List A) → (ys : List A) → length xs ≥ length ys → List A × List A`.

Comment: @user3237465 I'm used to strict functional programming languages like OCaml and hence I tend to use an accumulator. I keep forgetting that Haskell is non-strict. In OCaml we have both tail recursive and non tail recursive versions of `map`, etc.

Comment: Okay, this is the first time I've heard of this algorithm and it seems pretty neat and a quick google search gave me variations/alternates of it that accomplished goals different than yours. Would you please explain the goal that this particular floyd is supposed to accomplish. With such a specification in hand, we can then discuss a dependent type for it ;)

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy I added a visual example of how the algorithm works in the question.

Comment: Here's an attempt for a dependent type.

`∀ {n A} → (xs : Vec A n) → Σ left ∶ Vec A ⌈ n /2⌉  • Σ right ∶ Vec A ⌊ n /2 ⌋ • xs ≡ left ++ right`
where I write `Σ x ∶ X • Y` for the dependent product instead of `Data.Product`'s clunky `Σ[ x ∈ A] Y`
---eww looks like set theory!--- and the ceiling/floor properties can be found in
`Data.Nat.Properties`.

Of course, as others will note, a separation of concerns might be in order. If the proofs get out of hand, one might form the operation then prove that it satisfies the specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same thing as **Twan van Laarhoven** suggests in the comments but with `Vec`s. His version is probably better.

```
open import Function
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Product renaming (map to pmap)
open import Data.List.Base
open import Data.Vec hiding (split)

≤-step : ∀ {m n} -> m ≤ n -> m ≤ suc n
≤-step  z≤n     = z≤n
≤-step (s≤s le) = s≤s (≤-step le)

≤-refl : ∀ {n} -> n ≤ n
≤-refl {0}     = z≤n
≤-refl {suc n} = s≤s ≤-refl

floyd : ∀ {A : Set} {n m} -> m ≤ n -> Vec A n -> Vec A m -> List A × List A
floyd  z≤n            xs       []          = [] , toList xs
floyd (s≤s  z≤n)     (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ [])     = x ∷ [] , toList xs
floyd (s≤s (s≤s le)) (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ z ∷ ys) = pmap (x ∷_) id (floyd (≤-step le) xs ys)

split : ∀ {A : Set} -> List A -> List A × List A
split xs = floyd ≤-refl (fromList xs) (fromList xs)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

test₁ : split (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ 5 ∷ []) ≡ (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ [] , 4 ∷ 5 ∷ [])
test₁ = refl

test₂ : split (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ 5 ∷ 6 ∷ []) ≡ (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ [] , 4 ∷ 5 ∷ 6 ∷ [])
test₂ = refl
```

Also, functions like `≤-refl` and `≤-step` are somewhere in the standard library, but I was lazy to search.

---

Here is a silly thing I [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345899/how-to-enumerate-the-elements-of-a-list-by-fins-in-linear-time) to do:

```
open import Function
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Product renaming (map to pmap)
open import Data.List.Base
open import Data.Vec hiding (split)

floyd : ∀ {A : Set}
      -> (k : ℕ -> ℕ)
      -> (∀ {n} -> Vec A (k (suc n)) -> Vec A (suc (k n)))
      -> ∀ n
      -> Vec A (k n)
      -> List A × List A
floyd k u  0            xs = [] , toList xs
floyd k u  1            xs with u xs
... | x ∷ xs' = x ∷ [] , toList xs'
floyd k u (suc (suc n)) xs with u xs
... | x ∷ xs' = pmap (x ∷_) id (floyd (k ∘ suc) u n xs')

split : ∀ {A : Set} -> List A -> List A × List A
split xs = floyd id id (length xs) (fromList xs)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

test₁ : split (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ 5 ∷ []) ≡ (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ [] , 4 ∷ 5 ∷ [])
test₁ = refl

test₂ : split (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ 4 ∷ 5 ∷ 6 ∷ []) ≡ (1 ∷ 2 ∷ 3 ∷ [] , 4 ∷ 5 ∷ 6 ∷ [])
test₂ = refl
```

This is partly based on the **Benjamin Hodgson** suggestion in the comment below.

Comment: You can often dispense with proofs of `≤` by requiring that the length of one `Vec` be "something plus" the length of the other: `forall {m} -> Vec A n -> Vec A (n + m) -> ...`

Comment: I think you might have a typo since you're never making any real use of `ys` within `floyd` ... cf http://ideone.com/aKcgNZ which was posted by @user3237465 earlier as a comment

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy, the only use for `ys` we need is to shorten two times faster than `xs`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson But then you'd have to prove that you can split `n` into `ceil (n / 2) + floor (n / 2)` to kick off the algorithm. Which is what floyd seems to be doing in the first place.

Comment: `≤-refl` and `≤-step` are in `Data.Nat.Properties`