# Total real-time persistent queues

Tags: haskell, queue, dependent-type, gadt

Okasaki describes persistent real-time queues which can be realized in Haskell using the type

```
data Queue a = forall x . Queue
  { front :: [a]
  , rear :: [a]
  , schedule :: [x]
  }
```

where incremental rotations maintain the invariant

```
length schedule = length front - length rear
```

#### More details

If you're familiar with the queues involved, you can skip this section.

The rotation function looks like

```
rotate :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
rotate [] (y : _) a = y : a
rotate (x : xs) (y : ys) a =
  x : rotate xs ys (y : a)
```

and it's called by a smart constructor

```
exec :: [a] -> [a] -> [x] -> Queue a
exec f r (_ : s) = Queue f r s
exec f r [] = Queue f' [] f' where
  f' = rotate f r []
```

after each queue operation. The smart constructor is always called when `length s = length f - length r + 1`, ensuring that the pattern match in `rotate` will succeed.

#### The problem

I hate partial functions! I'd love to find a way to express the structural invariant in the types. The usual dependent vector seems a likely choice:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vec n a where
  Nil :: Vec 'Z a
  Cons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a
```

and then (perhaps)

```
data Queue a = forall x rl sl . Queue
  { front :: Vec (sl :+ rl) a
  , rear :: Vec rl a
  , schedule :: Vec sl x
  }
```

The trouble is that I haven't been able to figure out how to juggle the types. It seems extremely likely that *some* amount of `unsafeCoerce` will be needed to make this efficient. However, I haven't been able to come up with an approach that's even vaguely manageable. Is it possible to do this nicely in Haskell?

Comment: I don't think I understand this queue type - what would the types of `exec` and `rotate` be with the vector implementation?

Comment: What does `forall x . { ... ; schedule :: Vec sl x }` give you? It seems to me `schedule` is essentially a natural number, because the only thing you know about it is its length, since its contents is existentially quantified. So the type of `schedule` probably should be `Sing sl`.

Comment: @user3237465, `schedule` is indeed representing a natural number (and I introduced `x` specifically to make sure it's used *only* as a natural number), but it's actually a portion of the front list, so pattern matching on it drives incremental calculation of that list.

Comment: @user2407038, the type of `exec` could be expressed in various ways, depending on what works best, but one valid expression, I believe, is `Vec (sl1 :+ rl) a -> Vec rl a -> Vec ('S sl1) a -> Queue a`

Comment: So did you get things working? BTW, you should probably accept [the Alec's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40252235/3237465) as it's clearly more informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I got:

```
open import Function
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Vec

grotate : ∀ {n m} {A : Set}
        -> (B : ℕ -> Set)
        -> (∀ {n} -> A -> B n -> B (suc n))
        -> Vec A n
        -> Vec A (suc n + m)
        -> B m
        -> B (suc n + m)
grotate B cons  []      (y ∷ ys) a = cons y a
grotate B cons (x ∷ xs) (y ∷ ys) a = grotate (B ∘ suc) cons xs ys (cons y a)

rotate : ∀ {n m} {A : Set} -> Vec A n -> Vec A (suc n + m) -> Vec A m -> Vec A (suc n + m)
rotate = grotate (Vec _) _∷_

record Queue (A : Set) : Set₁ where
  constructor queue
  field
    {X}      : Set
    {n m}    : ℕ
    front    : Vec A (n + m)
    rear     : Vec A m
    schedule : Vec X n

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Nat.Properties.Simple

exec : ∀ {m n A} -> Vec A (n + m) -> Vec A (suc m) -> Vec A n -> Queue A
exec {m} {suc n} f r (_ ∷ s) = queue (subst (Vec _) (sym (+-suc n m)) f) r s
exec {m}         f r  []     = queue (with-zero f') [] f' where
 with-zero    = subst (Vec _ ∘ suc) (sym (+-right-identity m))
 without-zero = subst (Vec _ ∘ suc) (+-right-identity m)

 f' = without-zero (rotate f (with-zero r) [])
```

`rotate` is defined in terms of `grotate` for the same reason [`reverse` is defined in terms of `foldl`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Vec.agda#L150) (or [`enumerate` in terms of `genumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345899/how-to-enumerate-the-elements-of-a-list-by-fins-in-linear-time)): because `Vec A (suc n + m)` is not definitionally `Vec A (n + suc m)`, while `(B ∘ suc) m` is definitionally `B (suc m)`.

`exec` has the same implementation as you provided (modulo those `subst`s), but I'm not sure about the types: is it OK that `r` must be non-empty?

Comment: Wowzers. That `grotate` bit is going to take some thinking, since I have very little experience with this sort of programming. Is `subst` some sort of operation for pushing equalities into expressions? The restriction on `r` could be annoying, and that was my fault for a bad comment. Sorry about that. I doubt it would be horrible, but probably annoying.

Comment: @dfeuer, yes, `subst` rewrites the type of a term by an equation. In your comment it's a `schedule` must be non-empty (a typo?), while in mine it's a `rear`. That's just what other types enforced me to do. BTW, [here](https://gist.github.com/gallais/7bcb261f97dd395aa9d2) is an example of how `foldl` can be translated to Haskell, you'll probably need to do a similar thing to translate `grotate`.

Comment: I'm sorry for failing to award the bounty! I had no cell service for two days.

Comment: @dfeuer, no worries, the other answer deserves it better (even though it got only half of it).

Answer (score 3):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36612493/3072788) is super clever (please take a moment to upvote it), but as someone not familiar with Agda, how this would be implemented in Haskell was not obvious to me. Here's a full Haskell version. We'll need a whole slew of extensions, as well as `Data.Type.Equality` (since we will need to do some limited amount of type-proofs).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables,RankNTypes,
             TypeInType, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Type.Equality
```

#### Defining `Nat`, `Vec`, and `Queue`

Next, we define the usual type-level natural numbers (this looks like just a regular `data` definition, but because we have `TypeInType` enabled, it will get automatically promoted when we use it in a type) and a type function (a `type family`) for addition. Note that although there are multiple ways of defining `+`, our choice here will impact what follows. We'll also define the usual `Vec` which is very much like a list except that it encodes its length in the phantom type `n`. With that, we can go ahead and define the type of our queue.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family n + m where
    Z   + m = m
    S n + m = S (n + m)

data Vec a n where
    Nil   :: Vec a Z
    (:::) :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (S n)

data Queue a where
    Queue :: { front :: Vec a (n + m)
             , rear :: Vec a m
             , schedule :: Vec x n } -> Queue a
```

#### Defining `rotate`

Now, things start to get hairier. We want to define a function `rotate` that has type `rotate :: Vec a n -> Vec a (S n + m) -> Vec a m -> Vec a (S n + m)`, but you quickly run into a variety of proof related problems with just defining this recursively. The solution is instead to define a slightly more general `grotate`, which *can* be defined recursively, and for which `rotate` is a special case.

The point of `Bump` is to circumvent the fact that there is no such thing as type level composition in Haskell. There is no way of writing things an operator like `(∘)` such that `(S ∘ S) x` is `S (S x)`. The workaround is to continuously wrap/unwrap with `Bump`/`lower`.

```
newtype Bump p n = Bump { lower :: p (S n) }

grotate :: forall p n m a.
           (forall n. a -> p n -> p (S n)) ->
           Vec a n ->
           Vec a (S n + m) ->
           p m ->
           p (S n + m)
grotate cons Nil        (y ::: _)  zs = cons y zs
grotate cons (x ::: xs) (y ::: ys) zs = lower (grotate consS xs ys (Bump (cons y zs))) 
  where
    consS :: forall n. a -> Bump p n -> Bump p (S n)
    consS = \a -> Bump . cons a . lower 

rotate :: Vec a n -> Vec a (S n + m) -> Vec a m -> Vec a (S n + m)
rotate = grotate (:::)
```

We need explicit `forall`s here to make it very clear which type variables are getting captured and which aren't, as well as to denote higher-rank types.

#### Singleton natural numbers `SNat`

Before we proceed to `exec`, we set up some machinery that will allow us to prove some type-level arithmetic claims (which we need to get `exec` to typecheck). We start by making an `SNat` type (which is a singleton type corresponding to `Nat`). `SNat` reflects its value in a phantom type variable.

```
data SNat n where
  SZero :: SNat Z
  SSucc :: SNat n -> SNat (S n)
```

We can then make a couple useful functions to do things with `SNat`.

```
sub1 :: SNat (S n) -> SNat n
sub1 (SSucc x) = x

size :: Vec a n -> SNat n
size Nil = SZero
size (_ ::: xs) = SSucc (size xs)
```

Finally, we are prepared to prove some arithmetic, namely that `n + S m ~ S (n + m)` and `n + Z ~ n`.

```
plusSucc :: (SNat n) -> (SNat m) -> (n + S m) :~: S (n + m)
plusSucc SZero _ = Refl
plusSucc (SSucc n) m = gcastWith (plusSucc n m) Refl

plusZero :: SNat n -> (n + Z) :~: n
plusZero SZero = Refl
plusZero (SSucc n) = gcastWith (plusZero n) Refl
```

## Defining `exec`

Now that we have `rotate`, we can define `exec`. This definition looks almost identical to the one in the question (with lists), except annotated with `gcastWith <some-proof>`.

```
exec :: Vec a (n + m) -> Vec a (S m) -> Vec a n -> Queue a
exec f r (_ ::: s) = gcastWith (plusSucc (size s) (sub1 (size r))) $ Queue f r s
exec f r Nil       = gcastWith (plusZero (sub1 (size r))) $
  let f' = rotate f r Nil in (Queue f' Nil f')
```

---

It is probably worth noting that we can get some stuff for free by using [`singletons`](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons). With the right extensions enabled, the following more readable code

```
import Data.Singletons.TH 

singletons [d|
    data Nat = Z | S Nat

    (+) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
    Z   + n = n
    S m + n = S (m + n)
  |]
```

defines, `Nat`, the type family `:+` (equivalent to my `+`), and the singleton type `SNat` (with constructors `SZ` and `SS` equivalent to my `SZero` and `SSucc`) all in one.

Comment: This is very helpful indeed. I worked out the Agda `foldl` translation myself, but hadn't yet attempted this one. Note that `\a -> Bump . cons a . lower = (Bump .) . (. lower) . cons = ((Bump .) . (. lower)) #. cons`, which should be a free coercion. That leaves just `plusZero` and `plusSucc` to be optimized with unsafe coercions.