# Order of type arguments in indexed vectors

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

It seems conventional in dependently-typed programming to define

```
data Vec :: Type -> Nat -> Type where
  Nil :: Vec a 'Z
  Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a ('S n)
```

In Haskell, however, the `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Eq1`, `Ord1`, etc., classes seem to make a good case for flipping the arguments around, to `Vec :: Nat -> Type -> Type`.

Is there some important reason for the usual convention? Or is it just what people happen to use in languages not based substantially on type classes?

Comment: For what its worth, you aren't the first to have stumbled on this. [This](https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell-2015.html) post (which makes instance for most of the classes you mentioned) also has `Vec :: Nat -> Type -> Type`.

Comment: `Type -> Nat -> Type` is just the generally-more common order, in maths (`ℝ³` etc.) and currying-oblivious languages (`std::array<double, 3>`). Currying is what makes the Haskell order useful.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40252235/3072788) sort of trick with `Bump` isn't possible if the `Nat` doesn't occur in the last position.

Comment: @Alec, it's a bit less convenient, but it's still quite possible. You can either make `Bump` take an extra parameter or use `newtype Flip f x y = Flip { unFlip :: f y x }` to match things up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is not just conventional, but related to parameters vs. indexes in some dependently-typed languages. For example, Agda and Coq both require that parameters come before indexes in data type definitions. We would write

```
data Vec (A : Set) : Nat -> Set where ...
```

in Agda, because we want the `Set` argument to be treated as a parameter. If we would swap the argument order and write

```
data Vec : Nat -> Set -> Set where ...
```

instead, the `Set` argument would be treated as an index. We would still use it as a parameter in the constructor signatures, of course, but the Agda type checker would miss the information that it is a parameter.

In Haskell, the parameter order doesn't matter, so using an order that works well with currying is a good idea.

In Agda, I sometimes use the following work-around to get the currying right:

```
data Vec' (A : Set) : Nat -> Set

Vec : Nat -> Set -> Set
Vec n A = Vec' A n

{-# DISPLAY Vec' A n = Vec n A #-}

data Vec' A where
  nil : Vec zero A
  cons : {n : Nat} -> A -> Vec n A -> Vec (succ n) A
```

But I'm not sure the extra burden on the readers of the code is worth it.

Comment: Just that, yes. And vexing it often is, too. In Haskell, I put the length first...or generalise to funxtors on indexed sets.

Comment: Do you know *why* Agda behaves like that? Is it too expensive to check whether each argument is a parameter or an index (as GHC does)?

Comment: @dfeuer I guess GHC does not have to generate the associated induction principle form an inductive type, but Agda has to. Above, `A` can be chosen to be a parameter or an index, and each choice generates a different induction principle. There's no "right" choice, I think, which can be made by Agda, so it's better to let the use decide.

Comment: @chi, why would you ever want to treat a parameter as an index?

Comment: I'm not enough experienced to assess which one is better. But the generated induction principles are different, and that might matter. Even if one principle implies the other one, maybe the user wants to obtain the weaker one for some convenience reason (?). Anyway, autodeduction would make `a` in `data T a = B | K (T a)` as a parameter, and in `data T a = B  | K (T (F a))` as an index, AFAICS. I'd like the generated induction principles to be more consistent: if there are two options, make me choose which one.

Comment: The induction principle is part of the exposed interface of the type, so maybe the user plans to add more constructors that turn a parameter into an index, and wants to avoid changing the induction principle then.