# Why isn't Vector from sized-vector not a Functor, etc?

Tags: haskell

Why is the `a` parameter of `Vector` from [sized-vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector-1.4.3.1) 
have type Vector a n (with n the length) not the last type parameter? It prevents the creation of instances of Functor, Foldable, Traversable and Applicative and forces the duplication of some of their interfaces.

Comment: Weird... but does it matter? `sized-vector` is deprecated in favour of [`sized`, which _has_ a functor instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Sized.html).

Comment: It's inconvenient but not insoluble. You can define `newtype FlippedVec n a = FlippedVec { unFlipVec :: Vector a n }` and work with `FlippedVec`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of type arguments in indexed vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758994/order-of-type-arguments-in-indexed-vectors)