# Idris - Vector Queues and Rewrite Rules

Tags: vector, queue, idris

I'm trying to implement something like a functional queue in Idris, but which carries the number of elements in the type - such as `Queue ty n m (n+m)` where `n` is the number of elements in one `Vect n ty`, `m` is the elements in a second `Vect m ty`, and `(n+m)` is the total elements.

The problem is, I'm running into problems with applying rewrite rules when manipulating these sizes as implicit arguments:

```
module Queue

import Data.Vect as V

data Queue : Type -> Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    mkQueue : (front : V.Vect n ty)
           -> (back : V.Vect m ty)
           -> Queue ty n m (n + m)

%name Queue queue

top : Queue ty n m (S k) -> ty
top {n = S j} {m} {k = j + m} (mkQueue front back) =
    V.head front
top {n = Z} {m = S j} {k = j} (mkQueue front back) =
    V.head $ V.reverse back

bottom : Queue ty n m (S k) -> ty
bottom {m = S j} {n} {k = n + j} (mkQueue front back) = 
    ?some_rewrite_1 (V.head back)
bottom {m = Z} {n = S j} {k = j} (mkQueue front back) = 
    ?some_rewrite_2 (V.head $ V.reverse front)
```

`top` works but `bottom` does not.  It would appear that I somehow need to supply `plusZeroRightNeutral` and `plusRightSuccRight` rewrites, but I'm not sure where to put those, or whether there might be another option.  Here are the error messages:

Error on first line of `bottom`:

```
         Type mismatch between
                 Queue ty n (S j) (n + S j) (Type of mkQueue front back)
         and
                 Queue ty n (S j) (S (n + j)) (Expected type)

         Specifically:
                 Type mismatch between
                         plus n (S j)
                 and
                         S (n + j)
```

Error on second line of `bottom`:

```
         Type mismatch between
                 Queue ty (S j) 0 (S j + 0) (Type of mkQueue front back)
         and
                 Queue ty (S j) 0 (S j) (Expected type)

         Specifically:
                 Type mismatch between
                         plus (S j) 0
                 and
                         S j
```

The individual sizes tell me when I need to rotate the two `Vect`s, and the overall size tells me when I have an empty vs. non-empty `Queue`, so I do want to track all the information if possible.

Comment: As a remark, I wouldn't add the `front`/`back` size to the type, just the total size; I think the former is an implementation/representation detail that should be hidden from client code.

Comment: @Cactus: I've been moving my code over to that format, so that I would just have `Queue ty k`, where `k` in `MkQueue` is still `(n + m)` based on the sizes of the `Vect`s since that's an invariant I want to guarantee.  

However, then the problem I have is that I can't pull in `{n}` and `{m}` as implicits in the right place for `top` and `bottom` here.  Still working on that issue....

Comment: Related: [Total real-time persistent queues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611533/total-real-time-persistent-queues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way of solving this problem is to destruct `n` as well. This time Idris understands that the last argument is not zero, which it is basically complaining about:

```
total
bottom : Queue ty n m (S k) -> ty
bottom {m = S m} {n = S n} (MkQueue _ back) = V.head back
bottom {m = S m} {n = Z}   (MkQueue _ back) = V.head back
bottom {m = Z}   {n = S n} (MkQueue front _) = V.head $ V.reverse front
bottom {m = Z}   {n = Z}   (MkQueue _ _) impossible
```

As a side note, I'd suggest to make the `top` function total:

```
total
top : Queue ty n m (S k) -> ty
top {n = S n}           (MkQueue front _) = V.head front
top {n = Z}   {m = S m} (MkQueue _ back) = V.head $ V.reverse back
top {n = Z}   {m = Z}   (MkQueue _ _) impossible
```

Comment: Excellent - worked perfectly, solved the problem, and the note about totality was useful too.  Thanks!